# Correlation coefficient between rows of two matrices

Tags: matlab, statistics, distance

I have the following code, how will I be able to simplify it using the function as it currently runs pretty slow, assume `X` is 10x7 and `Y` is 4x7 and `D` is a matrix stores the correlation between each pair of vectors. If the solution is to use the `xcorr2` function can someone show me how it is done?

```
for i = 1:4
    for j = 1:10
        D(j,i) = corr2(X(j,:),Y(i,:));
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried preallocation? I can't test anything as I don't have the right toolbox but that should give a big speedup. before your loop add the line `D=zeros(10,4)`. Otherwise you can eliminate the inner loop with `bsxfun` which might help, but I can't test that

Comment: Otherwise maybe you should be suing `corrcoef` instead of `corr2` in your loop?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html) (Statistics toolbox) with `'correlation'` option. It's faster than your code (even with preallocation), and requires just one line:

```
D = 1-pdist2(X,Y,'correlation');
```

Comment: I guess this is the best solution for people with access to the statistics toolbox. Note that this may also require the transposition of `X` and `Y` compared to how they are described in the question.

Comment: @Thanks. I've edited my answer to mention the Statistics toolbox. Transposition is not required; `pdist2` works row-wise, as required by the original post

Comment: Nice reutilization of `pdist2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

First of all, store/process your matrix transposed. This makes for easier use of the correlation function.

Now assuming you have matrices `X` and `Y` and want to get the correlations between combinations of columns, this is easily achieved with a single loop:

1. Take the first column of `X`
2. use `corrcoef` to determine the correlation with all columns of `Y` at once.
3. As long as there is one, take the next column of `X`

---

Alternate to this, you can check whether it helps to replace `corr2` in your original code with `corr`, `xcorr` or `corrcoef` and see which one runs fastest.

Comment: I think `corrcoef(vector, matrix)` is not allowed by Matlab

Answer (score 0):

With `corrcoef` you can do this without a loop, and without using a toolbox:

```
D = corrcoef([X', Y']);
D = D(1 : size(X, 1), end - size(Y, 1) + 1 : end);
```

A drawback is that more coefficients are computed than necessary.

The transpose is necessary because your matrices do not follow the Matlab convention to enumerate samples with the first index and variables with the second.